# Customize Index Section With First Letter From Group In TableView

Tags: ios

I want to customize Index Section look like this

[image]

This is a screenshot I get from Snap-Hack app.

This Index Section just show The first letter of contact in list not A-Z index.

So I have 2 questions:
1. How can grab the first letter section
2. Use it in Index Section

Note: The list of friends is get from JSOn Data not in database

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) block-based data model initializer and do this with a few lines of code. The readme itself shows how to create "first letter" sections:

```
// multiple sections defined by an arbitrary code block
TLIndexPathDataModel *dataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:items sectionNameBlock:^NSString *(id item) {
    // organize items by first letter of description (like contacts app)
    return [item.description substringToIndex:1];
} identifierBlock:nil];
```

The block just needs to return a section name for the given item and you can substitute any logic you need.

**Update:**

The typical data model for a table with sections is an `NSArray` of section names and an `NSDictionary` of `NSArrays` containing the rows for each section. [`TLIndexPathDataModel`](http://tlindexpathtools.com/api/Classes/TLIndexPathDataModel.html) replaces all of that and provides APIs like `[dataModel numberOfRowsInSection:]` and `[dataModel itemAtIndexPath:]` to simplify your data model and delegate methods. For example, to implement section titles and index, you would do something like this:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataModel sectionNameForSection:section];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.dataModel sectionNames];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [self.dataModel sectionForSectionName:title];
}
```

To see this in action, take a look at the ["Blocks" sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Blocks/Blocks/BlocksTableViewController.m). This project uses a couple of additional classes `TLTableViewController` and `TLIndexPathController`, which you can learn about [in the README](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools). But you can just use `TLIndexPathDataModel` by itself if you want.

Comment: Tks, that's very helpful. But how can I implement it in indexsection?